# Работа с Excel в openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Нужно в столбец записать значения. В *A1*, *A2*, *A3*, *A4*, *A5* допустим нумерацию *1*, *2*, *3*, *4*, *5*. Не могу сделать через `for .. in ..`.

Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `for cell in ("A1", "A2", ...):` Или чуть умнее `for i in range(1, 6): cell = "A%d" % i; ...`. И ещё десятка два способов, но правильным будет всё же ленивый итератор. В общем покажите, что у вас пока вырисовывается?

Answer (score 0):

Если все правильно понял, то вам нужно нечто такое:

```py
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('range.xlsx')  # открывает файл с указанным названием
ws = wb['Лист1']  # Выбираем лист для работы

for num in range(10):
    row_num = num + 1  # нумерация строчек в экселе с 1
    ws['A' + str(row_num)].value = num  # в первый столбец "А" записываем индексы

wb.save('range.xlsx')
```

Конструкция `'A' + str(row_num)` позволяет обращаться к определенной ячейке. Буква тут отвечает за столбец, а `str(row_num)` за номер строки, который должен быть строкой, потому приходиться использовать метод `str()`.